# Error in yaml - possibly due to wrong escape, but unable to identify the issue

Tags: curl, json, yaml

The line below causes an error (...`request body malformed."}`).
It is part of a user-data.yml for use with cloud-init as part of the digital ocean api to bootstrap a server upon creation.

```
sed -ie '\$a\ \n\#Add logfile information\nlogfile /var/log/ntp.log' /etc/ntp.conf
```

Basically, it should do the following:

- append an empty line
- add a comment at the next line
- add string to
  next line

I am **loading** **that** **user-data.yml** **from a bash** script like following:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets" \
-d'{"name":"'$droplet_name'",
"region": "'$region'",
"size": "'$size'",
"image": "'$image'",
"backups":false,
"ipv6":false,
"private_networking":false,
"user_data":
"'"$(cat /user-data.yaml)"'",
  "ssh_keys": '$root_ssh_pub_key'}' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $api_key" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

After some hours hacking it all together I simply might be code blind.

Comment: Can you post the `/etc/ntp.conf` the `sed` is working on. The YAML files seems irellevant with regards to that, if not, please state the relation between the curl POST-ed YAML file and the `ntp.conf`

Comment: the ntp.conf is fine, the related entries exists - the issue is, the script dont fire at all with just that line added as it breaks the syntax. I assume I need to double escape everything as well as the dollar sign - just giving it a try, will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed gives "unterminated regex" on my system, you probably want to do something like:

```
echo abc > xy
sed -ie '$a\\n#Add logfile information\nlogfile /var/log/ntp.log' xy
cat xy
```

which gives:

```
abc

#Add logfile information
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

As for the YAML upload, I am not sure if that influences what you append to or not. If you cannot check the uploaded data,I  recommend generating the expanded YAML by writing it to file a `xyz.yaml` and then upload that with curl using `-d @xyz.yaml`. That gives you a chance to make sure you upload exactly what expected.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it - I appreciate that a lot. Maybe I should have been ,ore clear in my request: it won´t work as provided as it is sed within a yaml, therefore escaped as it gets pulled into bash, and then send as part of a jason. That seems to be the reason why I need to double escape everything. I found the solution a couple of minutes ago - will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it myself...

Should you work with DO API and following some tutorials like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-droplet-metadata) (middle of reference article) it´s likely you will run in either one of the following errors.

**Error 1** leads to something like `...request body malformed` To solve it make sure you did not forgot to escape any string/charackter within yaml.

**Error 2** won´t throw any issues at first sight. Your api request runs through, the droplet is spinned up and unless you did not do any fancy, you might even not notice it (if you don´t check what your script did to the system...). Checking the logs for cloud-init, however will show that it `failed loading yaml blob`. This is caused when charackters that requires escaping aren´t escaped often enough (?!).

**Example:**

- This will result in Error 1 (missed to escape the dollar charckter): 

  `sed -i -e '$a\ \n#Add logfile information\nlogfile /var/log/ntp.log' /etc/ntp.conf`
- This will result in Error 2 (the dollar is escaped chorecktly, but single escape isn´t enough here...):

   `sed -i -e '\$a\ \n#Add logfile information\nlogfile /var/log/ntp.log' /etc/ntp.conf`

So the solution is:

`sed -i -e '\\$a\\ \\n#Add logfile information\\nlogfile /var/log/ntp.log' /etc/ntp.conf`

If someone really is still reading and understands how frustrated I am, please let me know if you can explain what is going on here... - actually I am not really keen diving into this ever again but on the other side I am always willing to learn.

The only reason I would understand: As the bask script pulls a yaml and that bunch gets send through the remote shell in json it needs a little bit more "care" and therefore double escaping?!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to upload a JSON document consisting of several keys and values.  This document would be *malformed* if any of the values were invalid, for example, if a string containing characters that need particular JSON encoding, such as literal newlines and double quotes etc.

To ensure that all values are correctly encoded, it would help if you used some form of JSON processing tool, for example, [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) or [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/). Using such a tool would be preferable to manually preparing the data by escaping various characters etc.

---

Using `jq`:

```bash
jq -cn \
    --arg name "$droplet_name" \
    --arg size "$size" \
    --arg image "$image" \
    --argjson backups false \
    --argjson ipv6 false \
    --argjson private_networking false \
    --arg user_data "$(cat /user-data.yml)" \
    --arg ssh_keys "$root_ssh_pub_key" \
    '$ARGS.named'
```

Basically, use `--arg` for anything that this a string, and `--argjson` for values that aren't strings (numbers and booleans).

If `/user-data.yml` is a big document, you may want to let `jq` read it instead of expanding it on the command line:

```bash
jq -cn -Rs \
    --arg name "$droplet_name" \
    --arg size "$size" \
    --arg image "$image" \
    --argjson backups false \
    --argjson ipv6 false \
    --argjson private_networking false \
    --arg ssh_keys "$root_ssh_pub_key" \
    '$ARGS.named + { user_data: input }' /user-data.yml
```

This would also preserve the final newline character of the `/use-data.yml` file.

---

With `jo`:

```bash
jo \
    name="$droplet_name" \
    size="$size" \
    image="$image" \
    backups=false \
    ipv6=false \
    private_networking=false \
    user_data=@/user-data.yml \
    ssh_keys="$root_ssh_pub_key"
```

Here, I'm using `@` to let `jo` read and encode the user data file.  I could have used `use_data="$(cat ...)"`,
but since that is more to type, I opted for a shorter, easier-to-read variant.
Also note that `jo` infers the type of the values automatically, so instead of empty strings, you'd get `null` for missing values.

---

Whichever command you use, you may then pipe the output of that command directly into `curl`:

```bash
json-generating-command |
curl --silent --show-error \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $api_key" \
    --json @- 'some-URL-here'
```